# Why am I Gettign this Error ?: TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. at Main()

Tags: actionscript-3, button, flash-cs6

I am trying to make a small fanmade Zelda game. I am currently working on the menus, and have a small intro video that leads to the logo and start button being faded in. For some reason however my button is not removing the startPage and adding the filePage. My buttons name and ActionScript link in my library are "StartButton" and it is located in my StartPage movieclip. The filePage is also named "FilePage" aswell as it's AS3 link.

This is my code,

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    var startPage:StartPage;
    var filePage:FilePage;
    var introMusic:Sound = new IntroMusic;
    var introMusicChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

    public function Main()
    {
        introMusicChannel = introMusic.play();
        startPage = new StartPage;
        filePage = new FilePage;
        addChild(startPage);
        startPage.x = 275;
        startPage.y = -12.50;
        startPage.width = 795.95;
        startPage.height = 498.40;

   /*ADD EVENT LISTENERS
   ***********************/
        startPage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStartPageClick);
        startPage.StartButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
                    onStartButtonClick);
    }

   /*EVENT HANDLERS
   ***********************/
    function onStartPageClick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        startPage.gotoAndPlay(599);
    }

    function onStartButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        addChild(filePage);
        filePage.x = 275.00;
        filePage.y = 200.00;
        filePage.width = 599.90;
        filePage.height = 399.90;
        removeChild(startPage);
        introMusicChannel.stop();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Hooray for Zelda games (if you look at my profile pic).  Anyways, it says your `TypeError` is at the function `Main`.  Trace `'test'` in `Main` after defining your variables, and see if it gets traced before or after.  If after, then you know where to look for the error.  Then you can move `trace` higher and higher until you see what line it's on, or you can use `try` and `catch` to see the specific problem.

Comment: Debug your movie (ctrl+shift+enter) instead of testing (ctrl+enter), you will have more information about the problem and the line where it occurs.

Comment: It will be startPage.StartButton. What does startPage.getChildByName("StartButton") trace out?

Comment: @No clue. How do I check ? :p Sorry I am new to actionscript.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is this line.

```
startPage.StartButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStartButtonClick);
```

Goto StartPage MovieClip, select the StartButton and look into properties panel. Make sure your StartButton has "instance name" as StartButton in properties panel

[image]

Comment: That makes it not able to run at all.
The instance name MUST but lower-camel. It already has an instance name of "startButton".